# Flutter: How to use Material Icons in String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string and I would like to have an icon from the material icons displayed in that string. Currently, the only workaround is to use the standard emoji codes (e.g. `'\u26A0'`).

I'm not quite sure how to do this. The reason I can't use a widget here is because I'm using a validator, and if the amount of characters are not met, the validator returns a string that reads out what the issue is. I'm trying to add a warning icon to it.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please share some code.

Comment: why put the warning icon on the string itself instead of just on the widget that displays the string?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your use case is [WidgetSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html) here is simple example of how to use it

```dart
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: <InlineSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'call me'),
      WidgetSpan(
        child:Icon(Icons.phone)
      ),
    ],
  )
),
```

[image: UI result]